# How to make certain zones of a grid unclickable?

Tags: javascript

I have made the following code for a project which creates an interactive grid:

```
var lastClicked;
    var grid = clickableGrid(10,10,function(el,row,col,i){
    console.log("You clicked on element:",el);
    console.log("You clicked on row:",row);
    console.log("You clicked on col:",col);
    console.log("You clicked on item #:",i);
    el.className='clicked';
    if (lastClicked) lastClicked.className='';
    lastClicked = el;
    });
    document.body.appendChild(grid);

    function clickableGrid( rows, cols, callback ){
        var i=0;
        var grid = document.createElement('table');
        grid.className = 'grid';
        for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
            var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
            for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
                var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                cell.innerHTML = ++i;
                cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
                    return function(){
                        callback(el,r,c,i);
                    }
                })(cell,r,c,i),false);
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

I would like to make certain cells of the grid unclickable and have coded something which doesn't work:

```
        var incliquable = [document.getElementById("1"),document.getElementById("2"),document.getElementById("21"),document.getElementById("22"),document.getElementById("23"),document.getElementById("24"),document.getElementById("25"),document.getElementById("26"),document.getElementById("27"),document.getElementById("54"),document.getElementById("55"),document.getElementById("56"),document.getElementById("57"),document.getElementById("58"),document.getElementById("59"),document.getElementById("60"),document.getElementById("80"),document.getElementById("70")];
    if (element = incliquable) {
        document.getElementById(.grid td).style.cursor = pointer-events: none;
    }
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me find a way to make the pointer in CSS change to "pointer-events: none" in order to make the cells unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to something like this should help:

```
if (incliquable.indexOf(element) >= 0) {
  element.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  element.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
}
```

This is presuming your code properly sets `element` to a DOM element that you're testing against elements listed in `incliquable`.

Comment: ok great thank you!
I have tried the code however it does not work.
I think this is due to :
    var incliquable = [document.getElementById("1"),document.getElementById("2"),document.getElementById("21"),document.getElementById("22")];

Comment: I had to make some guesses since there were some confusing things about your code. Can you show where `element` is defined?

Comment: I'm new to coding so I don't really know how to call certain grid cells. Here is the code (without updating the suggestion): https://github.com/lea11458/DarwinsGame/blob/master/darwinsgame.html